# How not to remove child activity and go back to parent activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

What I am trying to do is kept all the data in a child activity and go back to a parent activity .

In other words, as far as stack structure, the child activity, which is located at the top of stack structure, should be kept and go back to parent activity.

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

One method you could use is starting the child activity using `startActivityForResult()`. Then once the child activity is closed, data is passed back to the parent activity.

If you then want to start the child activity again with the same data as before, you can check to see if the parent activity has any data from a previous result and parse it to the new child activity in the intent.

ParentActivity

```
String mData = null; //this goes above the parent's onCreate method, using a string as an example


//this is where you start the child activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChildActivity.class);
if(mData != null) {
    intent.putExtra("MyData", mData);
}

startActivityForResult(intent, mRequestCode);
```

ChildActivity

```
onCreate...

    if(getIntent().getStringExtra("MyData") != null) {
        //handle restoring the child activity to its previous state
    }
```

In you parent activity you could even get rid of the if statement as the child activity checks if the data sent is null.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one active activity at one moment of time. If you need to save state, serialize it to SharedPreferences or to your Database

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Fragment instead of activity. It is a better way I think than using activity.